# GoogleMap onMapReady fired well but not displaying on app

Tags: android

I have api key and I think I coded well but not displaying...

on app, google map fragment is shown like below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzQ10.jpg

on Java file

```
 public static GoogleMap map;

onCreate(){

...
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
//and it fires overrided onMapReady function

}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.e("dialog","on map ready");
        Log.e("dialog",googleMap.toString());
        map = googleMap;
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

 map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
                Log.e("dialog","map clicked"+arg0.toString());

            }
        });
}
```

on main.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/maps"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

Comment: Could it be because the zoom level is too high? Also, why are you making the map `public static`? The map has a reference to the activity context and it will be leaked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following possiblity of map not work please verify and check it,

- If your API key is validated then verify your SHA key and add latest key in credential section [Open key section](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=easternapp)
- Verify you added map api key in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like bellow

  > ```
  > <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  >  android:value="Your API KEY" />
  > ```
- Verify is `Map SDK for Android Enabled` or not
- Also after verifying all above step and then also not work.

  please try to reinstall your app.

Answer (score 0):

On top of adding your API key to your `AndroidManifest.xml` , be sure to add your app's package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to said API key through the Google Developer Console.

Also, make sure you've the API enabled within the Google Developer Console.